# Complicated limit of exponentials

Tags: limits, exponential-function, limits-without-lhopital

I am trying to evaluate a complicated limit, for which I have tried all the standard rules but to no avail (L'Hopitals, etc.). From numerical implementation, I think that the limit should be equal to $0$, but I have no idea how to approach the problem:

$$
 \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\alpha^x e^{-\alpha x}(\beta x)^x}{\Gamma(x+1)},
$$
where $\alpha>0$ and $0 \leq\beta\leq 1$.

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: Your $x$ is an integer? Otherwise $x!$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Noobmathematician Good point. Integers is fine. But if that complicates it, I am also fine with non-integers but then the factorial should be the gamma function I suppose.

Comment: Stirling formula may be handy here. If $x$ is not integer, I gather you take $\Gamma(x+1)$ instead right?

Comment: @OliverDiaz Yes correct. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Simpler with numerator written as $(\gamma x)^xe^{-\alpha x}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Stirling,

$$\frac{(\alpha\beta n)^ne^{-n\alpha}}{n!}\sim(\alpha\beta n)^ne^{-n\alpha}\frac{e^n}{\sqrt{2\pi n}n^n}=\frac{e^{n(1-\alpha+\log(\alpha\beta))}}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}.$$

The limit can be $0$ or $\infty$ depending on the sign of $1-\alpha+\log(\alpha\beta)$, which you have to discuss (this is relatively easy).

Comment: What is Stirling ? May I know ?

Comment: @Noobmathematician: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks! Very insightful.

Answer (score 1):

Using Stirling's formulas for $\Gamma(x)$ large values of $x$ gives

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\alpha^x e^{-\alpha x}(\beta x)^x}{\Gamma(x+1)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{e^{x(\log(\alpha\beta) -\alpha +1)}}{\sqrt{2\pi x}}
$$

All then depend on the reactions sign of $\log(\alpha\beta) -\alpha +1)$. This seems to at most zero (but I have not write down the details on paper yet) in which case the limit as you suspected is $0$.

Here is a picture to convince yourself that the exponent in the last limit is indeed at most $0$

[image]

Comment: It can be positive.

Comment: Yep, my bad, I considered the decimal log. With $\alpha=\beta=1$ you get $0$, but the limit is still $0$.

Comment: I think is actually nonpositive since $log(x)-x+\leq0$ and $\log\beta\leq0$ as $0\leq \beta\leq1$

Comment: @OliverDiaz Thanks! Under the assumption I have on $\beta$, it must indeed be true that limit goes to $0$.